# Classifier does not have a companion object , and thus must be initialized here

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

Mates, I am very new to kotlin and spring. I am trying to throw exepiion if record did not exist. I don't know the syntax how to wrap this line.
So this is my exeption class:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Record not found")
class NotFound : Exception()
```

So here is my code :

```
fun getUserById(userId: Int): User {
        return User(userRepository!!.findById(userId).orElse(ExeptionClass))//So the problem appears here
    }
```

So it says that: classifier ExeptionClass does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Comment: What is `ExeptionClass`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When I try to get non existing ID i want exeption to appear.

Comment: off-topic: Java's `Optional` is useless in Kotlin, it is much better  to create a method in your repo: `fun findById(id:Int): User?`. And then just use nullable type instead of Optional: `repo.findById(id) ?: ExeptionClass()`.  Also to get rid of those `!!` you have to inject repo through constructor using non-nullable type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to **throw** an exception. You thus want to use [`orElseThrow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-), and not `orElse()`.

So you need to pass a supplier (i.e. a lambda) that **creates** and returns an exception, by invoking its **constructor**. And the exception is named `NotFound`, not `ExeptionClass`. So the code should be

```
return User(userRepository!!.findById(userId).orElseThrow { NotFound() })
```